# Why doesn't try {} catch{} work in C#?

Tags: c#, error-handling

I have a `try{} catch{}` block in my program in Visual Studio. In the `try{}` block I have code to connect to a DB and when I run that program it returns an error. In this situation the program must execute the `catch{}` block, but an error is returned from the `try{}` block and the program stops.

```
try {
  using (OracleConnection cn = new OracleConnection(DataBase.EDS_SDE_Connection)) {
    cn.Open();
    using (OracleCommand cm = cn.CreateCommand()) {
      cm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
      cm.CommandText = "EDS_FEAUTRE_CLASSES.DIS_ENA_TRG_LOG";
      OracleParameter oParam = new OracleParameter("PISDISABLE", OracleDbType.Decimal);
      oParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
      oParam.Value = pIsDisable;
      cm.Parameters.Add(oParam);
      cm.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
  }
  bRet = true;
} catch (Exception ex) {
  ClsShares.ShowMessage("", ex.Message);
  bRet = false;
}
```

That's was from bellow highlighted chekbox:

[image]

Comment: what exception type did you catch? Maybe the exception thrown is not of the type (or inheriting type) caught

Comment: Show the code and the exception message and we can help in a better way.

Comment: This is my exeption
catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }
@KhanhTO

Comment: Are you running the application from VS IDE? try running from .exe

Comment: where does the error occur? are you saying that "ShowMessage" is never called?

Comment: Put a debug point in catch block and checks if exception is thrown by `ClsShares.ShowMessage("", ex.Message);` line. Or running the exe then log the message in log file.

Comment: @tofutim, yes, show message not running and run of program like there is no try catch stoped

Comment: @user1672994 program not arrived to catch block and stoped in try block

Comment: What is the error that you are getting?

Comment: do you know what the exception is? send a screenshot... sometimes in VS it will flag errors during debug even if there is a try-catch, you would have to go to debug config to turn them off

Comment: Probably the function 'ClsShares.ShowMessage("", ex.Message);' is throwing another error, that one can not be parsed and thus ni visible results

Comment: You really gotta tell the community what kinda error do you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not all exception types are enabled to break the solution by default. You can choose which are enabled from the Exception Setting window as you show above in the image.
Set the CLR exceptions set to be thrown. That's how the code will break (if there is no a try/catch) or in your case the try sequence will break and the catch block will be executed.

For different IDEs:

```
VS2015: Debug -> Windows -> Exception Settings.

VS2012: Debug -> Exceptions more details
```