# c# error show message in try catch block

Tags: c#, error-handling

I have a try catch like this that handled the error and give me a message box that shows the error, but in running i give error notification in try catch block and i'm so tired of that. This situation not happened before.what am i doing?
[image]

Comment: You just press `F5` and let it continue, it'll go to `catch`. But I do not see a code in `catch` to show any message box.

Comment: 1) Please use text (instead of screenshots) whenever possible.  2) Q: What am I doing?  A: You're getting an ArgumentOutOfRangeException trying to access `this.Controls[0]`.  3) If you had a non-empty catch block, you'd see the same exception, and it would point to the same line.  SUGGESTIONS: 1) fix "Controls[0]" by referencing your actual WinPart (whatever/wherever it is), then 2) implement a "catch Exception ex" block (and take the appropriate action).  Either in frmContainer_formClosing(), or at some higher-level.

Comment: You are not catching any type of exception. Your Catch block must have Exception Argument.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why doesn't try {} catch{} work in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33967818/why-doesnt-try-catch-work-in-c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to access the first element of this.Controls array (`this.Controls[0]`), but seems there are no elements in that.
Please check the array in debug mode and why the values are not in the object.

Note:
Never keep catch block empty, since it hides any exceptions and you will be in trouble when troubleshooting !